# Kendo grid custom filter

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-mobile

I am planning to use Kendo grid on a model (list of objects) which has many columns in HTML page.

For viewability, I have clubbed related model data in single column (like name, email, phone in single column).
Is it possible to provide custom filter for that column in kendo grid?

I am expected something like two dropdown on click of filter button and first drop down would show values like name, email, phone and second dropdown will have text box with contains filter.

Comment: Yes, it is: http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/filter-menu-customization

Answer (score -1):

```
 .Filterable(filterable => filterable
            .Extra(false)
            .Operators(operators => operators
                .ForString(str => str.Clear()
                    .Contains("شامل حروف ... باشد")
                    .StartsWith("با ... شروع شود")
                    .EndsWith("با ... تمام شود")
                    .IsEqualTo("برابر  باشد با")
                    .IsNotEqualTo("برابر نباشد با")
                    .DoesNotContain("شامل حروف ... نباشد")
                    .IsEmpty("خالی باشد")
                    .IsNotEmpty("پر باشد")
                    .IsNotNull("null نباشد")
                    .IsNull ("null باشد")
                ))
            )
```